# Can I access a derived class's non-virtual functions from a base class pointer?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

I have this code :

```
A * a = new A;
a->fun();
delete a;

a = new B;
a->fun();
delete a;
```

What I need to do is to make it print :

```
A::fun() //being printed by A's fun()
B::fun() //being printed by B's fun()
```

**without** using the virtual keyword. Classes can be altered although the main code has to remain unchanged. How can this be done?

(Also, `B` is derived from `A`)

Comment: @jrok Sorry I forgot to add that this is true. Check my edit.

Comment: @Luchian I see now how you got this to work, cool :)

Comment: Voted to close as too localized. This is far too specific to be of any use to anyone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this is for educational purposes.

If the destructor of `a` is not `virtual` this results in undefined behavior. So **the destructor must be `virtual`**.

If the destructor is `virtual`, you can use `dynamic_cast`. So, you can change `A::foo` to:

```
void A::fun()
{
   if ( dynamic_cast<B*>(this) )
       ((B*)this)->fun();
   else
       std::cout << "A::fun()";
}
```

#### Alternative with non-`virtual` destructor (undefined behavior if you call `delete`):

```
struct A
{
        bool isA;
        A(bool isA = true) : isA(isA){};
        void fun();
};
struct B : A
{
        B() : A(false){}
        void fun() {cout<<"B::fun()"<<endl;}
};

void A::fun()
{
        if (isA)
                std::cout << "A::fun()"<<endl;
        else
                ((B*)this)->fun();
}
```

Comment: This would arguably violate the OP's insane requirement not to use the `virtual` keyword... but I assume the OP isn't reporting the setup accurately.

Comment: @KerrekSB without a virtual destructor there's nothing to talk about... UB

Comment: @KerrekSB posted alternative without virtual destructor (although it doesn't prove anything).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do messy stuff, like storing the class in the instance data of A and have every constructor set the correct value, and making A::fun() check that and cast/redirect appropiately.

Or you could make your own equivalent of the virtual function table -- same as before, it's part of A's instance data, but filled in by the constructors for each class. Then, A::fun() would merely do something like MyTable->Fun().

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can help you to.

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
   A() : instance(0) { }
   A(B* p): instance(p) { }
   virtual ~A() { }
   void foo();
private:
   B* instance;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
   B():A(this) { }
   void foo() { std::cout << "B::foo" << std::endl; }
};

void A::foo()
{
   if (!instance)
   {
      std::cout << "A::foo" << std::endl;
      return;
   }
   instance->foo();
}
```

example http://ideone.com/Zd6cd